# Focus on parent window with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, window, focus

I cannot get focus on the opener in Firefox (but it's working in IE11).
Example from the firebug console:

- `popup = window.open(...)`
- Then in the opener

  window.focus()

=> The popup takes the focus

Now if from the popup I write

```
window.opener.focus()
```

=> nothing happens.

How to get focus on the opener again ?

Comment: I've found that sometimes I have to set the `opener` myself from the parent window, ie. `popup = window.open(...); popup.opener = this;`. It might help with your issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
window.parent.opener.focus();
```

You can use as well:

```
var myparent = window.open('', 'parent');
myparent.focus();
```

Comment: Hi,You probably mean `var myparent = window.open('', '_parent');` Anyway neither this nor setting the opener in the popup did work... It looks like some kind of protection or security rule, that only a popup may get the focus